# Naming conventions to be used when creating APIs in django to be consumed in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, rest, naming-conventions, api-design

I am creating a REST API in Django to be used in JavaScript. In python, the fields are all named using snake_case, but in JavaScript it is recommended to use camelCase for variable names.
How do I resolve this difference without having to rename them when I use them in JS, or do I just stick to one convention on both front and back end?